# Prevent application from flooding recycle bin

Tags: windows, disk-space, recycle-bin, screen-recorder

I have the PlaysTV application on my computer for recording gameplay moments. The application has a limited space for saving video before it starts deleting the older video. Unfortunately instead of just deleting the videos for good, the application moves the old videos to my Recycle Bin. This leads to tens of gigabytes of trash on my hard drive, and I have to manually empty the recycle bin.

The application has no settings for fixing this problem and I couldn't seem to find any help online. So the question is: *Is there any way to set a single application to delete files permanently on Windows?*'

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: If I'm writing a program that arbitrarily deletes content, I would expect that using the recycle bin is more respectful of the users data than not. you may be miffed that you have to empty the recyclebin every couple days, and need to schedule a script to deal with it, but users who lost files they actually wanted would be livid. Coders have to ride the line between user extremes, and deleting stuff is an inherently dangerous operation from that perspective.

Comment: @FrankThomas Then again, it's deleting its own files and I assume it uses a circular buffer. In that case it is hardly "arbitrarily deleting content", it's just deleting the older data as it is supposed to. For me this kind of functionality is just baffling: if it only puts it into recycle bin, there is no actual need to delete anything to begin with since it's not freeing any space. It could just not delete and have the same effect. As for the question itself, I don't know any method of telling Windows to disable recycle bin for a single application.

Comment: @FrankThomas I think you are both right. The videos are stored in a folder inside the users Videos folder and the location can be changed. I have heard this accidentally deleting files unwantedly. What I find to be wrong is that there's no option to change it. It is understandable that the developer doesn't want to risk people's files, but the user should be allowed to change it on their own responsibility. Currently I'm trying to create a batch script for startup that can automatically delete the matching files from the Recycle Bin using regex. If I do get it to work I will post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I bet this program has a setting to delete instead of moving it to the recycle bin.

If this pc is only used for PlaysTV, you may want to consider disabling the recycle bin, which deletes the files directly rather than moving them to the recycle bin.

A third option is to set a limit on how much data can be moved to the recycle bin.

Altering settings for the recycle bin can be done as follows:

Minimize all programs so you see the desktop. Right click on the recycle bin and choose properties.

From this dialog you can change the maximum size or disable the recycle bin altogether.